# event.keyCode constants

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

When testing JavaScript in Firefox 3.5, I have access to constants such as `KeyEvent.DOM_VK_D`, but not in Google Chrome.

Is there a cross-browser way of accessing these constants?

Comment: This answer to a similar question points to a great library that solves this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed/303024#303024

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can define the [*KeyEvent* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/UIEvent/KeyEvent) if it doesn’t exist:

```
if (typeof KeyEvent == "undefined") {
    var KeyEvent = {
        DOM_VK_CANCEL: 3,
        DOM_VK_HELP: 6,
        DOM_VK_BACK_SPACE: 8,
        DOM_VK_TAB: 9,
        DOM_VK_CLEAR: 12,
        DOM_VK_RETURN: 13,
        DOM_VK_ENTER: 14,
        DOM_VK_SHIFT: 16,
        DOM_VK_CONTROL: 17,
        DOM_VK_ALT: 18,
        DOM_VK_PAUSE: 19,
        DOM_VK_CAPS_LOCK: 20,
        DOM_VK_ESCAPE: 27,
        DOM_VK_SPACE: 32,
        DOM_VK_PAGE_UP: 33,
        DOM_VK_PAGE_DOWN: 34,
        DOM_VK_END: 35,
        DOM_VK_HOME: 36,
        DOM_VK_LEFT: 37,
        DOM_VK_UP: 38,
        DOM_VK_RIGHT: 39,
        DOM_VK_DOWN: 40,
        DOM_VK_PRINTSCREEN: 44,
        DOM_VK_INSERT: 45,
        DOM_VK_DELETE: 46,
        DOM_VK_0: 48,
        DOM_VK_1: 49,
        DOM_VK_2: 50,
        DOM_VK_3: 51,
        DOM_VK_4: 52,
        DOM_VK_5: 53,
        DOM_VK_6: 54,
        DOM_VK_7: 55,
        DOM_VK_8: 56,
        DOM_VK_9: 57,
        DOM_VK_SEMICOLON: 59,
        DOM_VK_EQUALS: 61,
        DOM_VK_A: 65,
        DOM_VK_B: 66,
        DOM_VK_C: 67,
        DOM_VK_D: 68,
        DOM_VK_E: 69,
        DOM_VK_F: 70,
        DOM_VK_G: 71,
        DOM_VK_H: 72,
        DOM_VK_I: 73,
        DOM_VK_J: 74,
        DOM_VK_K: 75,
        DOM_VK_L: 76,
        DOM_VK_M: 77,
        DOM_VK_N: 78,
        DOM_VK_O: 79,
        DOM_VK_P: 80,
        DOM_VK_Q: 81,
        DOM_VK_R: 82,
        DOM_VK_S: 83,
        DOM_VK_T: 84,
        DOM_VK_U: 85,
        DOM_VK_V: 86,
        DOM_VK_W: 87,
        DOM_VK_X: 88,
        DOM_VK_Y: 89,
        DOM_VK_Z: 90,
        DOM_VK_CONTEXT_MENU: 93,
        DOM_VK_NUMPAD0: 96,
        DOM_VK_NUMPAD1: 97,
        DOM_VK_NUMPAD2: 98,
        DOM_VK_NUMPAD3: 99,
        DOM_VK_NUMPAD4: 100,
        DOM_VK_NUMPAD5: 101,
        DOM_VK_NUMPAD6: 102,
        DOM_VK_NUMPAD7: 103,
        DOM_VK_NUMPAD8: 104,
        DOM_VK_NUMPAD9: 105,
        DOM_VK_MULTIPLY: 106,
        DOM_VK_ADD: 107,
        DOM_VK_SEPARATOR: 108,
        DOM_VK_SUBTRACT: 109,
        DOM_VK_DECIMAL: 110,
        DOM_VK_DIVIDE: 111,
        DOM_VK_F1: 112,
        DOM_VK_F2: 113,
        DOM_VK_F3: 114,
        DOM_VK_F4: 115,
        DOM_VK_F5: 116,
        DOM_VK_F6: 117,
        DOM_VK_F7: 118,
        DOM_VK_F8: 119,
        DOM_VK_F9: 120,
        DOM_VK_F10: 121,
        DOM_VK_F11: 122,
        DOM_VK_F12: 123,
        DOM_VK_F13: 124,
        DOM_VK_F14: 125,
        DOM_VK_F15: 126,
        DOM_VK_F16: 127,
        DOM_VK_F17: 128,
        DOM_VK_F18: 129,
        DOM_VK_F19: 130,
        DOM_VK_F20: 131,
        DOM_VK_F21: 132,
        DOM_VK_F22: 133,
        DOM_VK_F23: 134,
        DOM_VK_F24: 135,
        DOM_VK_NUM_LOCK: 144,
        DOM_VK_SCROLL_LOCK: 145,
        DOM_VK_COMMA: 188,
        DOM_VK_PERIOD: 190,
        DOM_VK_SLASH: 191,
        DOM_VK_BACK_QUOTE: 192,
        DOM_VK_OPEN_BRACKET: 219,
        DOM_VK_BACK_SLASH: 220,
        DOM_VK_CLOSE_BRACKET: 221,
        DOM_VK_QUOTE: 222,
        DOM_VK_META: 224
    };
}
```

See also [*KeyEvent* in DOM Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20010410/DOM3-Events.html#events-Events-KeyEvent).

Comment: So are the constants in Firefox's KeyEvent expected to be standard in future?

Comment: Will throw *ReferenceError* if `KeyEvent` doesn't exist. Use `typeof` instead.

Comment: @Liam Sure. When `KeyEvent` is undeclared, a *ReferenceError* will be thrown. Checking with `typeof` avoids it - `if (typeof KeyEvent == 'undefined')`

Comment: I found this useful, but how is the link _KeyEvent in DOM Level 3_ relevant? Agreed, I couldn't find any other definitive list, but it doesn't match what is accurate (it says ENTER is 0x0c, 12, which isn't what currently browsers report). At least add a note?

Comment: There's a help key!?! `DOM_VK_HELP` Where is it? If only there was a help key to help me find the help key!

Answer (score 16):

The standardisation process for keyboard input in web browsers has been ongoing for only the last 15 years or so. It turns out that it's not a simple problem.

In [2010](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20100907/#events-KeyboardEvent-key) the KeyEvent interface was replaced with KeyboardEvent by W3C in a working draft. The list of DOM_VK_ key codes has not seen further standardisation work and is unlikely to ever be made consistent: some of the key codes differ between platforms, and even between browsers on the same platform. The KeyboardEvent interface is an attempt to bring in some consistency for key events.

However, as of writing this comment, [browser compatibility for KeyboardEvent could be described as a disaster zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Browser_compatibility). Few browsers support [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), but this will hopefully become more consistently available in the future. It is a string which describes the key, rather than a numeric value. The list of proposed values is a [W3C Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events-key/).

I found one [shim for KeyboardEvent.key](https://github.com/termi/DOM-Keyboard-Event-Level-3-polyfill), but it is apparently not currently up to date with the specification.

It is still possible that this story will have a happy ending.

Answer (score 13):

Also you can use a lightweight npm package [keycode-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycode-js). This contains a list of all these keycode constants and is easy to use.

Here's how you use it, https://github.com/kabirbaidhya/keycode-js#usage

```js
// You may use either the numeric code value or the code to identity the key.
console.log("Return key code:", KeyCode.KEY_RETURN);
console.log("Return key name:", KeyCode.CODE_RETURN);
console.log("Return key value:", KeyCode.VALUE_RETURN);

// Use it in the event handler
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  // You may do one of these checks.

  // Check the code value.
  if (e.code === KeyCode.CODE_RETURN) {
    console.log('It was the Return key.');
    return;
  }

  // OR, check the keyCode value.
  if (e.keyCode === KeyCode.KEY_RETURN) {
    console.log('It was the Return key.');
    return;
  }

  // OR, check the key value.
  if (e.key === KeyCode.VALUE_RETURN) {
    console.log('It was the Return key.');
    return;
  }

  console.log('It was any other key.');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/keycode-js@3.1.0/dist/keycode.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the list of [supported constants](https://github.com/kabirbaidhya/keycode-js#all-constants). This list based on the official list of key event codes listed in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#Constants_for_keyCode_value).

This package is nothing more than a list of key codes like this:

```
exports.KEY_CANCEL = 3;
exports.KEY_HELP = 6;
exports.KEY_BACK_SPACE = 8;
exports.KEY_TAB = 9;
exports.KEY_CLEAR = 12;
exports.KEY_RETURN = 13;
exports.KEY_ENTER = 14;
exports.KEY_SHIFT = 16;
exports.KEY_CONTROL = 17;
exports.KEY_ALT = 18;
exports.KEY_PAUSE = 19;
exports.KEY_CAPS_LOCK = 20;
exports.KEY_ESCAPE = 27;
exports.KEY_SPACE = 32;
exports.KEY_PAGE_UP = 33;
exports.KEY_PAGE_DOWN = 34;
exports.KEY_END = 35;
exports.KEY_HOME = 36;
exports.KEY_LEFT = 37;
exports.KEY_UP = 38;
exports.KEY_RIGHT = 39;
exports.KEY_DOWN = 40;
exports.KEY_PRINTSCREEN = 44;
exports.KEY_INSERT = 45;
exports.KEY_DELETE = 46;
exports.KEY_0 = 48;
exports.KEY_1 = 49;
exports.KEY_2 = 50;
exports.KEY_3 = 51;
exports.KEY_4 = 52;
exports.KEY_5 = 53;
exports.KEY_6 = 54;
exports.KEY_7 = 55;
exports.KEY_8 = 56;
exports.KEY_9 = 57;
exports.KEY_SEMICOLON = 59;
exports.KEY_EQUALS = 61;
exports.KEY_A = 65;
exports.KEY_B = 66;
exports.KEY_C = 67;
exports.KEY_D = 68;
exports.KEY_E = 69;
exports.KEY_F = 70;
exports.KEY_G = 71;
exports.KEY_H = 72;
exports.KEY_I = 73;
exports.KEY_J = 74;
exports.KEY_K = 75;
exports.KEY_L = 76;
exports.KEY_M = 77;
exports.KEY_N = 78;
exports.KEY_O = 79;
exports.KEY_P = 80;
exports.KEY_Q = 81;
exports.KEY_R = 82;
exports.KEY_S = 83;
exports.KEY_T = 84;
exports.KEY_U = 85;
exports.KEY_V = 86;
exports.KEY_W = 87;
exports.KEY_X = 88;
exports.KEY_Y = 89;
exports.KEY_Z = 90;
exports.KEY_CONTEXT_MENU = 93;
exports.KEY_NUMPAD0 = 96;
exports.KEY_NUMPAD1 = 97;
exports.KEY_NUMPAD2 = 98;
exports.KEY_NUMPAD3 = 99;
exports.KEY_NUMPAD4 = 100;
exports.KEY_NUMPAD5 = 101;
exports.KEY_NUMPAD6 = 102;
exports.KEY_NUMPAD7 = 103;
exports.KEY_NUMPAD8 = 104;
exports.KEY_NUMPAD9 = 105;
exports.KEY_MULTIPLY = 106;
exports.KEY_ADD = 107;
exports.KEY_SEPARATOR = 108;
exports.KEY_SUBTRACT = 109;
exports.KEY_DECIMAL = 110;
exports.KEY_DIVIDE = 111;
exports.KEY_F1 = 112;
exports.KEY_F2 = 113;
exports.KEY_F3 = 114;
exports.KEY_F4 = 115;
exports.KEY_F5 = 116;
exports.KEY_F6 = 117;
exports.KEY_F7 = 118;
exports.KEY_F8 = 119;
exports.KEY_F9 = 120;
exports.KEY_F10 = 121;
exports.KEY_F11 = 122;
exports.KEY_F12 = 123;
exports.KEY_F13 = 124;
exports.KEY_F14 = 125;
exports.KEY_F15 = 126;
exports.KEY_F16 = 127;
exports.KEY_F17 = 128;
exports.KEY_F18 = 129;
exports.KEY_F19 = 130;
exports.KEY_F20 = 131;
exports.KEY_F21 = 132;
exports.KEY_F22 = 133;
exports.KEY_F23 = 134;
exports.KEY_F24 = 135;
exports.KEY_NUM_LOCK = 144;
exports.KEY_SCROLL_LOCK = 145;
exports.KEY_COMMA = 188;
exports.KEY_PERIOD = 190;
exports.KEY_SLASH = 191;
exports.KEY_BACK_QUOTE = 192;
exports.KEY_OPEN_BRACKET = 219;
exports.KEY_BACK_SLASH = 220;
exports.KEY_CLOSE_BRACKET = 221;
exports.KEY_QUOTE = 222;
exports.KEY_META = 224;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used the solution from @Gumbo for quite some time now.  Because I have multiple projects that need this object, I've simply created a bower package for it.  If someone already has done this, let me know...

Simply `bower install keyevent -S` and include the `bower_components/src/keyevent.js` in your build process.

**Note**: this library is dumb, if the KeyEvent instance already exists, this will likely clobber it.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/cybertoothca/keyevent

`bower info keyevent` to get information about the project.