# How can I deal with different keyCodes on different browsers?

Tags: javascript, keycode

I've seen some forums posts about different browsers reporting different keyCodes, but everyone seems so avoid the "why?".

I was trying to capture the colon (:) keyCode and realized that Firefox reports back e.keyCode 56.  While Chrome reports back 186 (I think that's what it was).

Is there a universal way of getting the right keyCode across all browsers?

And why are they different if they are the same keys?

I would be more curious as to whether there is a international way of getting the same key press.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: @galambalazs, this chart does not account for colon and semi-colon. Which suprises me.  PPK is usually on top of that sort of thing.

Comment: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html has the colon and semi-colon, and seems pretty exhaustive.

Comment: KeyEvent (and hence keyCodes) is [basically deprecated and being replaced with KeyboardEvent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33860580/1836776). This is not an answer as to why different browsers report different keyCodes but hopefully a pointer to what will potentially be a good solution in the future. Potentially.

Comment: Related: *[Key codes in different browsers? jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439658/key-codes-in-different-browsers-jquery)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html for an explanation why they have different keys.  I do not know of an international way to match keys.

Comment: The conclusion part of the link I included contains some information that may help you implement a universal solution -- just depends on your situation.

Comment: Nice article you linked me to.

Comment: That is a link-only answer. The link still works, but can you provide a summary (in your own words) here?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 8 years ago"*

Answer (score 18):

It depends whether you're interested in which physical key the user has pressed or which character the user has typed. If it's the character you're after, you can get that reliably in all major browsers (using the `keypress` event's `which` property in most browsers or `keyCode` in IE <= 8), but only in the `keypress` event. If you're after the key, use the `keydown` or `keyup` event and examine the `keyCode` property, although the exact key-code mappings do differ somewhat between browsers.

An excellent explanation of and reference for all JavaScript key-related events can be found at http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html.

To detect the user typing a colon character reliably in all the major browsers, you could do the following:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (charCode && String.fromCharCode(charCode) == ":") {
        alert("Colon!");
    }
};
```

Comment: charCode != keyCode, except for /[A-Z 0-9]/

Comment: @NathanBubna: I know. However, in old IE's `keypress` event, `keyCode` confusingly *is* the character code, not a key code, and all other mainstream browsers support `which`, so `keyCode` is only used in old IE. Read all about it at http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html (as linked to in my answer).

Comment: Ick. Old IE strikes again. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

The modern way to do this is use event.key. See [MDN Key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

Comment: This is still the current way, considering Key is still in draft and not supported on most mobile browsers http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key

Comment: suit your self, it's not very far off. It's worth noting that the far and away most popular mobile browser, Chrome for android has full support. The biggest gotchas are iOS and Safari, though Safaris' support is coming in the next version. I would recommend using one of the many available polyfills.

Comment: Actually you can use it. It's supported for most used browsers. (http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key) If the property is undefined you can still use a small fallback function.

Comment: Note that there are differences, however, in some modern browsers. For example, pressing the dot key (`.`/`Del`) on a Num Pad with the Num Lock on reports the event.key as "Del" in Edge, but reports it as "." in Chrome. People keep suggesting that Safari is the new Internet Explorer. Lately I wonder if Edge is actually the new Internet Explorer. Oh, wait.

Answer (score 1):

### 2022 - `event.key` gives the "logical" key, `event.code` gives the "physical" key

Some examples tested on macOS [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox), Windows [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge), and Windows [Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome):

| `event.key` | `event.code` |
| --- | --- |
| "Enter" | "Enter" |
| "Enter" | "NumpadEnter" |
| "8" | "Digit8" |
| "8" | "Numpad8" |
| "/" | "Slash" |
| "/" | "NumpadDivide" |

### Edge cases

- Windows Chrome/Edge, when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> the `event.key` is `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make JavaScript to get the keycode of the ':' character, so the script will know what is it in a certain environment. Similar question had been asked [here, in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430989).

Answer (score 0):

Have also a look at this GitHub file: *[key-to-charCode/jQuery.getChar.js](https://github.com/bpeacock/key-to-charCode/blob/master/jQuery.getChar.js)* on how you can use keyDown instead of keyPress events.

I used this for a barcode scanner with a keyboard wedge, on a mobile device that had a bug on returning (keyPress) data for scanning a hyphen. It worked pretty good. Except when I tested the app in a browser with a regular keyboard, I noticed that the hyphen works on Chrome, but not on Firefox. Strange, but true. Fixed by adding code 173 in the above JavaScript file, in addition to code 189.

This makes me wonder what the keyboard is actually sending. The keydown code of 173 or 189 for pressing the hyphen key (- _) is apparently not sent by the keyboard itself, but created by the browser that sends the keyDown event to my JavaScript application.

Comment: Possibly related: *[JavaScript: different keyCodes on different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883543/javascript-different-keycodes-on-different-browsers)*

Answer (score 0):

2023 here, and I've been using a different solution to this for a long time.

It involves using a hidden textarea to get the typed character. It is a bit of a hack, but it works flawlessly in all major browsers and saves the headache of working with *e.key*, *e.keyCode*, etc.

I'll just post the code here. It's fairly self-explanatory. If you're wanting this to work in *all* mobile browsers, including [Opera Mini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini), etc. then you'll have to change the fixed positioning to absolute positioning and make sure the textarea is always positioned around the middle of the visible part of the page to avoid scrolling whenever a character is typed.

Basically, create a hidden textarea, add a keydown event to the window object that focuses the textarea, get the value of the textarea, clear the textarea, focus the previously focused element again...and optionally then generate the typed character in the previously focused element.

```
/* Create a hidden textarea */
var keyGrabber = document.createElement('textarea');
keyGrabber.style.border = '0';
keyGrabber.style.margin = '0';
keyGrabber.style.padding = '0';
keyGrabber.style.outline = 'none';
keyGrabber.style.position = 'fixed';
keyGrabber.style.top = '0';
keyGrabber.tabIndex = '-1';

document.body.appendChild(keyGrabber);

/* Avoid confusion for screen readers */
keyGrabber.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');

/* Init the variables here so they are global and easy to access */
var oldActiveElement = document.activeElement;
var oldStart = 0;
var oldEnd = 0;

/* Catch the keydown event and store the active elements
   selection start and end in case you still want the
   character to be typed */
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    oldActiveElement = document.activeElement;
    oldStart = oldActiveElement.selectionStart;
    oldEnd = oldActiveElement.selectionEnd;
    keyGrabber.focus();
    /* If you need to capture keys that don't generate
       written characters, you'll have to do that here
       using e.key || e.keyCode */
});

keyGrabber.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var character = keyGrabber.value;
    if(character == ':') {
        alert('You typed a colon!');
        /* Replace alert with whatever code you want
           to execute when a colon is typed */
    }
    keyGrabber.value = '';
    oldActiveElement.focus();
    /* This part is optional, in case you want to still
       have the typed character generate in an input
       and also fire the event. You would then also
       replace "window.addEventListener..." with
       "yourInput.addEventListener..." */
    var part1 = oldActiveElement.value.slice(0, oldStart);
    var part2 = oldActiveElement.value.slice(oldEnd, oldActiveElement.value.length);
    oldActiveElement.value = part1 + character + part2;
    oldActiveElement.selectionStart = oldStart + 1;
    oldActiveElement.selectionEnd = oldActiveElement.selectionStart;
});
```

Please don't copy/paste this code and expect it to work flawlessly. I'm typing this from memory and not copying it from a working file. I can't remember if setting the tabIndex to -1 stops the .focus() from working. I think it's fine, but please double check this.