# Key codes in different browsers? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, keycode

All I have found about this is that there are inconsistencies among different web browsers when it comes to key codes.

I have the following code that runs fine when pressed enter in Safari, Opera and Chrome, but not in Firefox.

I use Firefox 9.0.1.

Here are two code snippets where the problem occurs:

1)

```
// Post something
$('#postDiv').on('keydown', '#posttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
        post($(this));
    }
});
```

2. 

```
// Comment on a post
$('.commenttext').live('keydown', function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
    }
});
```

Both functions aren't even called.

I did some more testing only with `e.which` and noticed that it works when I leave out the `&& !event.shiftKey` - apparently Firefox doesn't know that command. Is there any alternative to that? I would like the user to be able to hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> without submitting the post. I have already tried the condition `if (e.which==13 && e.which!=16)`, but to no avail.

#### Solution

First of all thank you for all answers! Of course it had to be `e.shiftKey`, not `event.shiftKey`! Now it works in all browsers (the only one I haven't tried yet is Internet Explorer).

Comment: Just use `event.which` for consistent result across browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode#Notes

Comment: Why did you make this question if it's already solved in your other question? (use `e.which` only, jQuery normalizes it.)

Comment: Try to bind the keydown on a document and then identify the element with $(this).attr('id') . Maybe that helps a bit ?

Comment: Thanks! I did some more testing only with e.which and noticed that it works when I leave out the && !event.shiftKey - apparently FF doesn't know that command. Is there any alternative to that? I would like the user to be able to hit shift+enter without submitting the post. I have already tried the condition if (e.which==13 && e.which!=16) but to no avail.

Comment: thanks, found the solution, see question edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.
>   It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.

You shouldn't need to use e.keyCode and you may be running into issues where e.which != 13 but e.keyCode does. Have you verified the issue continues after removing the e.keyCode evaluation out of your control structures?

Comment: Thanks! I did some more testing only with e.which and noticed that it works when I leave out the && !event.shiftKey - apparently FF doesn't know that command. Is there any alternative to that? I would like the user to be able to hit shift+enter without submitting the post. I have already tried the condition if (e.which==13 && e.which!=16) but to no avail.

Comment: According to [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.shiftKey), event.shiftKey should return a boolean in Mozilla. Have you tried a console.log(e.shiftKey) to verify what's being returned in each browser?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do both `keyCode` and `which`, just use `which` and that'll do you fine in all browsers :)

http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: +1 for which. I can learn bits of different things everyday on SO!

Comment: @lukas.pukenis as do I! Every day is a school day here on SO ;) hehe