# What is the key code of dot (.) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I need to define some event for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. What is the number of dot-key-code? I want something like these:

<kbd>Enter</kbd> is 13.

<kbd>S</kbd> is 83.

<kbd>2</kbd> is 50.

According to [this website](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

What is it for <kbd>.</kbd>?

Comment: You could console log the event and find out youself

Comment: You can find it on this website [https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode](https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode)

Comment: There is some confusion about the kind of codes. From *"[What are the JavaScript KeyCodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603195/what-are-the-javascript-keycodes/5871443#5871443)"* (though it may not be authoritative): *"keyCodes are different from the ASCII values"*

Comment: Related: *[JavaScript: different keyCodes on different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883543/javascript-different-keycodes-on-different-browsers)*

Comment: con't - [E.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883543/javascript-different-keycodes-on-different-browsers/74378706#74378706), *"event.key gives the "logical" key, event.code gives the "physical" key"* (as a string, not a number)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to that [same website](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes), the <kbd>.</kbd>'s dot-key code is 190.

Comment: No problem, There's a search box on the website, here you can enter any character you want and it will give you the keycode, please don't forget to mark the correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. @stack

Answer (score 6):

According to the website, key-code for `.` is 190.

Comment: I've experienced the same, got 46 for dot .

Comment: [It depends](https://blog.pothoven.net/2008/05/keydown-vs-keypress-in-javascript.html) on whether it's a "key down" or "key press" event and whether you're looking at "key code" or "char code".

Comment: Related: *[JavaScript: different keyCodes on different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883543/javascript-different-keycodes-on-different-browsers)*

Answer (score 5):

110 is also a dot. But from the numpad.  Be aware/careful!

Answer (score 2):

46 works for me

```js
function logKeyCode(event){
   const keyCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    console.log('keyCode =',keyCode);
   if(keyCode==190 || keyCode==110 || keyCode==46){
      console.log('keyCode . detected');
      alert('keyCode . detected');
   }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="logKeyCode(event)" />
```

Comment: This is actually a better solution.

Comment: But this will accept 'n' also as 110 is code for 'n'

Comment: What is the explanation? 46 is the ASCII code for dot (.). Why must it include three different values, 190, 110, and 46? What is the justification for it? What are those three [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))? Is one for the [numeric keypad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad)? We expect more than a code dump in a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: cont' - Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60202192/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Related: *[JavaScript: different keyCodes on different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883543/javascript-different-keycodes-on-different-browsers)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are customising a keyboard for your app, don't use any misleading keylabel...

KeyCode of the dot (.) character is 56.

For your custom keyboard...

```
<Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="." />
```

*or*

```
<Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="." />
```

Comment: this answers headline looks random can you try rephrase/elaborate it so it's more useful?

Comment: Is 56 a typo? The [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) of "`.`" is 46. And isn't it the character code, not the key code?

Answer (score 0):

For `Angular 8` it was **46** that worked for me

```
@HostListener("keypress", ["$event"]) onKeyPress(event) {
        let keyCode = parseInt(event.keyCode);

        if (keyCode == 46) {
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And then? Why is there a difference? 46 (decimal) is [the ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) for "`.`". Are you sure it is the same kind of code as in the question?

Comment: OK, *[JavaScript: different keyCodes on different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883543/javascript-different-keycodes-on-different-browsers)*

Comment: What browser, incl. version, was it tested on?

Answer (score 0):

In my case 110 & 190 are the KeyCodes for `.`

This is an amazing website where you can find any keycode

https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode