# JavaScript: Avoiding hardcoded keycodes

Tags: javascript, keycode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript event.keyCode constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465374/javascript-event-keycode-constants)

This is my code:

```
$button.on('keyup', function (event) {
    // Detect an Enter keypress
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        doStuff();
    }
});
```

As you can see, the keycode `13` is hardcoded. Is there a (cross-browser) way to fish out that number in a more semantically meaningful way?

Comment: If there is anything more semantic and clean than ASCII decimal codes, I've never seen it. Of course you can make a map `var keys = { enter: 13 }` and fish it through `event.code === keys.enter`, but I personally prefer to see the actual keycodes to be sure of what the script is doing without looking up an object's definition. And no, there are no cross-browser/platform issues with the Enter key as far as I'm aware.

Comment: just define an object with keycodes a values , and key names as keys. There is no built in enum for that.

Comment: `"\r".charCodeAt(0)` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465374/javascript-event-keycode-constants

Comment: Despite my initial comment, a key map may be useful when you're manoeuvring with many keys e.g. mapping all arrows keys would be more semantic than writing a number for each. `=]`

Comment: @AlexK. Pretty smart hack to get the keycode of the carriage return without hardcoding it as OP requested, could be an answer imo. `=]`

Comment: Just in case you want to use a separate package. Here's a lightweight npm package with these keycode constants https://github.com/kabirbaidhya/keycode-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repeat `Alex K.`'s answer (I used):

```
"\r".charCodeAt(0)
```

Answer (score 9):

If you work with **jQueryUI**, you may use [`$.ui.keyCode`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.core.js#L27) constants:

```
keyCode: {
    BACKSPACE: 8,
    COMMA: 188,
    DELETE: 46,
    DOWN: 40,
    END: 35,
    ENTER: 13,
    ESCAPE: 27,
    HOME: 36,
    LEFT: 37,
    NUMPAD_ADD: 107,
    NUMPAD_DECIMAL: 110,
    NUMPAD_DIVIDE: 111,
    NUMPAD_ENTER: 108,
    NUMPAD_MULTIPLY: 106,
    NUMPAD_SUBTRACT: 109,
    PAGE_DOWN: 34,
    PAGE_UP: 33,
    PERIOD: 190,
    RIGHT: 39,
    SPACE: 32,
    TAB: 9,
    UP: 38
}
```

So in order to check for <kbd>Enter</kbd> pressed use:

```
if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) { ... }
```

Comment: These of course aren't the only keyCodes that are constant cross-browser right? @Vision

Comment: The shifting sands of time have broken that link; [here's a working one](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/e9643f6bfc922773e29e3084e64de0240b547f32/ui/core.js#L29-L46) (as of October 2014)