# How to detect escape key press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyevent, jquery-events

How to detect escape key press in IE, Firefox and Chrome?
Below code works in IE and alerts `27`, but in Firefox it alerts `0`

```
$('body').keypress(function(e){
    alert(e.which);
    if(e.which == 27){
        // Close my modal window
    }
});
```

Comment: do some browser detection first?

Comment: I find quirksmode.org always reliable to find out what works in which browser: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html . There you can find that only `keyup` or `keydown` in combination with `keyCode` works in all browsers.

Comment: I think the title of this question should be "How to detect escape key press with jquery?" Or the answers should be in native javascript...

Comment: `$(document).on("keyup", function (e) {var code = e.keyCode || e.which; alert('key pressed: ' + code);});` Greetings from the 2014

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which keycode for escape key with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery)

Comment: Deprecated/Unsafe -> should use e.key == "Escape"

Answer (score 1232, accepted):

Note: `keyCode` is [becoming deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), use `key` instead.

```
function keyPress (e) {
    if(e.key === "Escape") {
        // write your logic here.
    }
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
var msg = document.getElementById('state-msg');

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.key == "Escape") {
    msg.textContent += 'Escape pressed:'
  }
});
```

```html
Press ESC key <span id="state-msg"></span>
```

---

`keyCode` and [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) are deprecated.

> It seems `keydown` and `keyup` work.

---

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.key === "Escape") { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
        // <DO YOUR WORK HERE>
    }
});
```

[Which keycode for escape key with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery)

Comment: to unbind: $(document).unbind("keyup", keyUpFunc);

Comment: To unbind you can also use a namespace on the event, `$(document).on('keyup.unique_name', ...)` and `$(document).unbind('keyup.unique_name')`

Comment: It is recommended to use e.which (instead of e.keycode) to check which key was pressed. jQuery normalizes keycode and charcode (used in older browsers)

Comment: @DMTintner : on the same subject, see the comment left by Jordan Brough http://stackoverflow.com/a/1160109/759452

Comment: You should always use `===`.

Comment: @pmandell: Other than code style reasons such as consistency, there is no benefit at all to using `===` over `==` here.

Comment: @LachlanMcD - be aware (5 years later!) that [`.unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) is now deprecated as of jQuery 3.0... you should use [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: e.keyCode is deprecated.

Comment: It seems Chrome does not allow intercepting the Escape key. "keydown" used to work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901063/jquerys-keypress-doesnt-work-for-some-keys-in-chrome-how-to-work-around/5479683), but it seems Google has disabled that as well.

Comment: @Spero https://jsfiddle.net/t0bmuaxw/ I tested in latest chrome available as of today (`69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) 21st Sep, 18` keydown is working

Comment: The long list of **key values**:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values

Comment: `keypress` does **not** work for `Escape`. Use `keydown` (or `keyup`) instead.

Comment: keypress event is deprecated.

Answer (score 287):

The `keydown` event will work fine for Escape and has the benefit of allowing you to use `keyCode` in all browsers. Also, you need to attach the listener to `document` rather than the body.

**Update May 2016**

`keyCode` is now in the process of being deprecated and most modern browsers offer the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property now, although you'll still need a fallback for decent browser support for now (at time of writing the current releases of Chrome and Safari don't support it).

**Update September 2018**
[`evt.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is now supported by all modern browsers.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var isEscape = false;
    if ("key" in evt) {
        isEscape = (evt.key === "Escape" || evt.key === "Esc");
    } else {
        isEscape = (evt.keyCode === 27);
    }
    if (isEscape) {
        alert("Escape");
    }
};
```

```html
Click me then press the Escape key
```

Comment: Note, you can also add the listener to an `<input>` element and it will therefore only be triggered when this element has focus.

Comment: You can also check `if (evt.key === 'Escape') {` instead of using the deprecated `keyCode`

Comment: @Keysox: For most modern browsers, yes, although you still need fallbacks for now. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: FYI, [MDN's reference to keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) (includes the deprecation node)

Comment: If you want to know if you can safely use `.key`, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key

Comment: It seems there's no way in Chrome to get the keydown event from any element, though, when Escape has a form field lose focus (blur).
You can try by running the above code snippet, then giving focus to the "Your Answer" text field and hitting "Escape".
If anyone has a reliable workaround for this, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 46):

Using [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) you can do check working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9w8m/)**

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        alert('Esc key pressed.');
    }
};
```

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can do check working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQHVa/1/)**

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup',function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
       alert('Esc key pressed.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Intellij says your vanilla js code snippet is deprecated. When should I stop using it ?

Answer (score 28):

### Pure JS

you can attach a listener to `keyUp` event for the document.

Also, if you want to make sure, any other key is not pressed along with `Esc` key, you can use values of `ctrlKey`, `altKey`, and `shifkey`.

```
 document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        
        if (event.key === 'Escape') {
         //if esc key was not pressed in combination with ctrl or alt or shift
            const isNotCombinedKey = !(event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.shiftKey);
            if (isNotCombinedKey) {
                console.log('Escape key was pressed with out any group keys')
              
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 21):

check for `keyCode` && `which` & `keyup` || `keydown`

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
   alert(code);
});
```

Comment: i see this not working, http://jsfiddle.net/GWJVt/ just for the escape... seems awkward?

Comment: $(document.body).keypress() is not firing

Comment: @Reigel: indeed, seems not to work properly with keypress. Whatsoever, I can't figure the 'awkward' part.

Comment: KeyPress is raised for character keys (unlike KeyDown and KeyUp, which are also raised for noncharacter keys) while the key is pressed.

Answer (score 15):

pure JS (no JQuery)

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
      //add your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering this question, per site guidelines please add some explanatory text to explain how/why this works. Thanks!

Comment: As I research and check here https://onecompiler.com/html/3xy2mfps5. It's better to use key down as it fires for all kinds of keys pressed and use keyCode or code to do UI change(eg; close modal when the user clicks on the escape key).

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated

Answer (score 12):

Below is the code that not only disables the ESC key but also checks the condition where it is pressed and depending on the situation, it will do the action or not.

In this example,

```
e.preventDefault();
```

will disable the ESC key-press action.

You may do anything like to hide a div with this:

```
document.getElementById('myDivId').style.display = 'none';
```

Where the ESC key pressed is also taken into consideration:

```
(e.target.nodeName=='BODY')
```

You may remove this if condition part if you like to apply to this to all. Or you may target INPUT here to only apply this action when the cursor is in input box.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if((e.key=='Escape'||e.key=='Esc'||e.keyCode==27) && (e.target.nodeName=='BODY')){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 8):

Best way is to make function for this

**FUNCTION:**

```
$.fn.escape = function (callback) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(document).on("keydown", this, function (e) {
            var keycode = ((typeof e.keyCode !='undefined' && e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (keycode === 27) {
                callback.call(this, e);
            };
        });
    });
};
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$("#my-div").escape(function () {
    alert('Escape!');
})
```

Comment: Actually, it seems that `keypress` doesn't fire on the escape key. At least, not in Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback, I made a update and change rule. `keydown` fix the problem.

Comment: I updated your solution to be able to support an 'only once'-usage. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/oxok5x2p/ .

Comment: Cool solution fo rthe only once

Answer (score 3):

i think the simplest way is vanilla javascript:

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 27){
     //do something here
   }
}
```

Updated: Changed key => keyCode

Comment: On my chrome (Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)) I get `Escape` as `event.key` and not 27

Comment: It should be `event.keyCode` to be 27.

Answer (score 3):

On Firefox 78 use this ("keypress" doesn't work for Escape key):

```
function keyPress (e)(){
  if (e.key == "Escape"){
     //do something here      
  }
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyPress);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple javascript code to detect Escape key is pressed

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
  if(e.key === "Escape") {
    console.log("Escape key pressed")
  }
});
```