# jQuery's 'keypress' doesn't work for some keys in Chrome. How to work around?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, keypress

I'm trying to implement key-press functionality which will remove a div when the user hits `Esc`. This works for Firefox & IE with the following code:

```
$("body").keypress(function(e) {
    alert("any key pressed");
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        alert("escape pressed");
    }
});
```

If I hit any key, the first `alert` is displayed, and if I hit Escape, the second `alert` is also displayed.

This doesn't work with Chrome though. The first `alert` is always displayed if I hit any of the letter keys, but not when I hit Escape, Tab, Space or any of the numbers.

Why would this be? Is there any way to get Chrome to respond to these key presses?

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9061) of Chrome.  In May 2016 a developer stated that they think their behaviour fits the spec better and [will not fix it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9061#c15).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try handling `keydown` instead.

Comment: The trick to this answer, which I think is very important to note, is that "try handling `keydown`" is not a general purpose solution, but specific to "some keys".  You still need `keypress` to handle the ascii characters correctly. So it's really a (muddled) multi-step process.

Comment: Does anyone know why this is implemented as such?

Comment: @MaxStrater: `keypress` is only for actual characters.

Comment: `keyup` is slightly better for replicating `keypress` functionality since it doesn't fire until the user releases the key.

Comment: @DanT: On the contrary.  If he wants to replicate `keypress`, he'll _want_ the repeated `keydown`s.

Comment: Note: keydown fires multiple times when the key is hold down. While keypress should only fire once when pressing a key. They are not the same.

Answer (score 20):

use **keydown**.
keypress doesn't work with ESC in Chrome (not sure about other browsers).

```
$(newTag).keydown(function(e) {  //keypress did not work with ESC;
    if (event.which == '13') {
      ProfilePage.saveNewTag(search_id, $(newTag).val());
    }
    else if (window.event.which){
      $(newTag).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the Chrome bug. It will be helpful to those wondering why keypress is actually working for them in other browsers.

Comment: neither `keypress` nor `keyup` doesn't work for ESC key on Chromium 69.0.3497.92. on linux. `keydown` works flawlessly

Answer (score 2):

For ESC key:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 27) { /* Run code */ }
}
```

For letter keys, like 'L':

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 108) { }
});
```

Works in both Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1):

After the second alert add also

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This will prevent the default action of the event to be triggered.

More info about this method [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Your code should look like

```
$("body").keypress(function(e) {
    alert("any key pressed");
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
         alert("escape pressed");
         e.preventDefault();
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

**keypress 'ESC'**

```
e.which: 0
e.keyCode: 27
```

**keyup 'ESC'**

```
e.which: 27
e.keyCode: 27
```

---

For non-printable characters better use `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery.hotkey js file you can Make Sortcut key

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'esc', function(){ });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.