# Toggle class via ESC key using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I've set up a jQuery function to add a class to the body on pressing the ESC key.

How can I change the code below to toggle between adding and removing the class on key press, rather than just adding it once?

```
if(key.code == 27 && $(document.body).hasClass('preview-mode'))
     $(document.body).removeClass('preview-mode');
```

Comment: Check out jQuery's [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: Thankyou! One of those questions where in hindsight a Google search would have been better as it's so obvious, but I wrongly assumed it would be more complicated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(key.code == 27)
    $(document.body).toggleClass('Your_class_2'); //set your default class as preview-mode
```

for more : [jQuery Effects](http://codewithlogic.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/jquery-ui-demystified-part-3/)

[Toggle Class](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/asiniw/2)

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** `keypress` will not catch escape key in google-chrome https://stackoverflow.com/a/3901076/829533

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function(e){

        if(e.keyCode == 27) {
            if ($('body').hasClass('preview-mode')) {
                $('body').removeClass('preview-mode');
            } else {
                $('body').addClass('preview-mode');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/tcPfQ/3/

OR with `toggleClass`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function(e){

        if(e.keyCode == 27) {
            $('body').toggleClass('preview-mode');
        }
    });
})
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/tcPfQ/2/