# Gridview exit edit mode using ESC and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, escaping

Is is possible to exit the edit mode in a Gridview using JavaScript when a key (ex. ESC) is pressed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the escape key press using JavaScript, check this answer: [How to detect escape key press with JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-javascript/3369624#3369624) (using JQuery)

The switch out of the GridView's edit-mode has to happen on the server side, so you need to invoke a post-back from JavaScript. An easy way to do this is adding a normal ASP.Net button to your page, hiding it with CSS, and then invoking it's click method using JQuery.

Sample:

```
<asp:Button id="btnPostBackHook" runat="server" onClick="MyServerSidedMethod" style="display: none;" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $('#<%=btnPostBackHook.ClientID%>').click();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Once you've posted back to the server, I believe you can set `myGridView.EditIndex = -1;` to exit edit mode.

Comment: I have already done the catch for the escape key but how do I invoke the postback using your idea? Can I see the code?Thanks

Comment: I've added a sample to my answer.