# Targeting lower layer to close a modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple modal box opening like this:

```
<div id="social" class="overlay">
  <div class="inner">
    <a class="close" href="#"><span class="icon-close"></span></a>

    CONTENT

 </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.overlay { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 100; 
    background: fade(@black, 75%); 
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;   
}

#social .inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1000;  
    width: 380px;
}
```

And here is the JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#social").css("height", $(document).height());

    $(".social").click(function(){
        $("#social").fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

    $(".close").click(function(){
        $("#social").fadeOut();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The modal box closes when someone clicks on the link with the class `close`. I'd like the modal box to *also* close when someone clicks anywhere outside the modal box, so anywhere on the **overlay** layer (`z-index:999`). I don't know how to target the lower layer (`z-index:999`) without also affecting the top layer (`z-index:1000`).

I don't know much about jQuery, so if you could phrase your suggestions in a newbie way, that'd be great. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fade out the modal box when the overlay is clicked by attaching a click event handler on the overlay. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4B72F/1/)

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="social" value="test" />
<div id="social" class="overlay">
    <div class="inner"> 
        <a class="close" href="#">
            <span class="icon-close">X</span>
        </a>
        CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#social .inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 380px;
}
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#social").css("height", $(document).height());

     $(".social").click(function () {
         $("#social").fadeIn();
         return false;
     });

     $(".close").click(function () {
         $("#social").fadeOut();
         return false;
     });


     //This is the part that handles the overlay click
     $("#social").on('click', function (e) {
         if (e.target == this) {
             $(this).fadeOut();
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! But this will close the modal box also when I click on the content (the actual modal box). I only want it to close when I click outside the modal box, i.e. on the background.

Comment: One more question: if I wanted to hide the modalbox also by pressing the ESC key, is there an easy way for this?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-javascript). Bind the keyup event to the overlay, should work.