# Close overlay on click or escape key

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created an overlay which covers the entire page, I am looking for a way to either click on the body to close the overlay and/or using the escape key:

```
  <div id="navigationPop" class="myContent">
    <ul>
      <li>Search</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $("#"+divId).fadeToggle();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

escape:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { <DO YOUR WORK HERE> }   // esc
});
```

[How to detect escape key press with JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-javascript)

Click outside overlay:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    //Hide the menus if visible
});

$('#menucontainer').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: Hey, So where in the first example it says do your work here....is there I would input my bit of script? I tried but it disabled the trigger