# Redirect on Key Press?

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-shortcuts

So I have a website and I am looking for a way to redirect a user to another webpage when they press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the keydown event and capture the event.key, and if event.key === "Escape", you issue a redirect. Like so:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
        window.location.replace("/*your url here*/");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use keycode 27 for ESC keys. See the below answer for more details.
[How to detect escape key press with JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-javascript-or-jquery)