# Capture Browser Stop Button

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Can I use JavaScript to detect when a page load is cancelled or stopped? This occurs when the browser's stop button is clicked. I do not wish to capture the `esc` button and would like to capture a browser event that occurs when the browser button is clicked.

Comment: @mplungjan your duplicate does not provide a solution and that answer is a hack that does not answer this question

Comment: It was the top one I found. Click on the other links I posted and then tell us which code you tried and why they did not work for you. If you want to determin esc over stop, then you are likely needing a hack anyway

Comment: [How to detect escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-pure-js-or-jquery)

Comment: You're looking for [window.onabort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onabort) event, which most browser's don't seem to fire

Comment: onabort looks great. thank you so much