# changing value from select tag in reactjs on firefox browser of windows

Tags: reactjs, select, frontend

I'm using a select tag that would display a set of options (refer to snippet below)

```
<select onChange = {(e)=>{console.log("in change}}
        name="pets" id="pet-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Spider</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>
```

The issue is that on pressing esc also the value is being changed on windows firefox, is there any way to reject the change if event is fired through esc button

Note: I'm using reactjs

Comment: use `onKeyPressDown` event to prevent esc button click.

Answer (score 0):

## Current Answer

TLDR for this answer is that after providing 2 attempts at this answer I've tried to do further research but I cannot find a working answer (myself). It looks like perhaps because `<select>` uses the native dropdown it's not possible to prevent this action? Hopefully, someone can correct me if I am incorrect. In truth to respond to this question, I would recommend building your own [custom dropdown component in React](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-a-custom-dropdown-menu-component-for-react-e94f02ced4a1/) as this will give you an opportunity to experiment with fundamentals in React anyways and gives you full control of your component.

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/kjscott27/pen/JjGQWbZ) of two examples where I was grabbing the key events on a Select component but to be honest, the event capturing was iffy at best and as I said above I think the interference of the native components (like the dropdown) from the browser will prevent you from altering any functionality here.

---

## Other Answers

Answer partly taken from here: [How to detect escape key press with pure JS or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-pure-js-or-jquery)

You'll need to capture the escape key by using an if statement to detect if that particular key was pressed onKeyDown and preventing the default behavior of that key using the event you're passing in.

Answer 1:

```
<select 
  onChange = {(e) => console.log("in change")}
  onKeyDown = {(e) => {
    if(e.key === "Escape") {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  name="pets" id="pet-select"
>
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Spider</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>
```

Edit: Other Tips (I fixed in the code above):
When you're only returning a console log you don't have to wrap it with {} you can just plainly return the console log on its own. You also had some syntax errors in that piece of code you posted for the console.log that I cleaned up.

Answer 2:
This answer is using [React's hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) where we are creating a reference to the select element with our useRef hook. We then take that current reference and add an event listener for keydown (and prevent escape).

```
const Element = () => {
  const selectRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (selectRef.current) {
      selectRef.current.addEventListener("keydown", handleOnKeyDown);
    }

    return () => {
      selectRef.current.removeEventListener("keydown", handleOnKeyDown);
    };
  }, [selectRef, selectRef.current]);

  const handleOnKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Escape") {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  return (
    <select name="pets" id="pet-select" ref={selectRef}>
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <option value="dog">Dog</option>
      <option value="cat">Cat</option>
      <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
      <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
      <option value="spider">Spider</option>
      <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
    </select>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried the onKeyDown event but after opening the dropdown, I cannot receive the key pressed, values are being returned until dropdown is closed.

Comment: Hmm, to be honest that makes sense now that I've had a think about it.. This is a scenario where you perhaps are looking to use a ref from Reacts [useRef hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). With this, you could add an event listener on component mount and add a "keydown" "eventListener" that takes a function which takes the event from the keydown and prevents the default (as I shared previously) if its the escape key. I'll try to edit my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with my findings over the last little while, let's see if anyone else can maybe addon to what I've said but I think a custom component is just the way to go.