Woocommerce - Menu button slideToggle speed not being applied
I'm making a custom menu for mobile and am trying to get a search bar to slide up when the menu button is clicked.
I've pretty much managed to get it working using a combinaiton of Add Search Toggle Icon at End of Menu in WordPress, and Create a Custom Navigation Menu in WordPress Without Using Plugins but for some reason the toggle speed isn't being applied.
Here's what I have so far:
function my_custom_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_menu' );

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpb_add_search_toggle', 10, 2);
// Filter in Search Toggle to end of primary menu
function wpb_add_search_toggle($items, $args) {
    $items_array = array();
        while ( false !== ( $item_pos = strpos ( $items, '<li', 3 ) ) ) // Add the position where the menu item is placed
        {
            $items_array[] = substr($items, 0, $item_pos);
            $items = substr($items, $item_pos);
        }
        $items_array[] = $items;
        array_splice($items_array, 2, 0, '<li class="search search-wpb"><a class="search-icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a><div style="display:none;" class="wpbsearchform">'. get_search_form(false) .'</div></li>'); // insert custom item after 2nd item one

        $items = implode('', $items_array);

    return $items;
}

function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    /* Search Menu */
    
    $(".search-icon").click(function() {
        $(".wpbsearchform").slideToggle(200);
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        // Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-pure-js-or-jquery
        // Close search if esc key pressed
        if (e.key == "Escape") {
          $(".wpbsearchform").slideToggle(200);
        }
    });

});
</script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');

The '.slideToggle(200)' doesn't work, I've also tried '.slideToggle("slow").
Trying to alter the transition speed with css has also been ineffective using the following:
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
.search-wpb .fa-search {
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.search-wpb .fa-search:hover, 
.search-wpb .fa-search:focus {
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wpbsearchform{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 60px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: rgba(200,199,197,0.8);
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border: none;
    transition: all 200ms;
}
    
.wpbsearchform input#s {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
    
.wpbsearchform span.fa.fa-lg.fa-search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 35px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
    
.wpbsearchform form#searchform:hover {
    background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Mobile-Store-bottom-120-noresize.jpg) !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position-y: top !important;
}

.wpbsearchform form input:focus {
    color: #555;
}
    
.wpbsearchform ::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999 !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    opacity: 1;
}

.wpbsearchform ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #999 !important;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.wpbsearchform form#searchform {
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: unset !important;
    bottom: 60px;
    background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Mobile-Store-bottom-120-noresize.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: top;
    padding: 10px !important;
    transition: all 200ms;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 60px;
}
}

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

You show the css of the form but what about .wpsearchform since this is what you target ? Make sure you dont use conflicting css like display: flex; or overflow: hidden;. Also use  $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {} instead of  $(document).keyup(function(e) {}

Also, you should replace $(".search-icon").click(function() { with $(".search-icon").on('click', function() {…
Note that for the "keyup" event, as is intended to close/hide the element, you should use slideUp() instead of slideToggle().

@Snuffy, thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question to include the rest of the css, please let me know if anything stands out that might be interferring with the slideTogle speed. Have updated to '$(document).on('keyup', function(e)', thanks for the suggestion.

@LoicTheAztec, have updated to '$(".search-icon").on('click', function() {', thanks for the suggestion.

So it looks like this is causing the issue: .wpbsearchform form#searchform { position: fixed !important; } With it removed the slideToggle speed is applied.
Unfortunately with 'position: fixed' removed the search bar is limited to the width of the button, rather than being full page width (width: 100%). Any idea how I can keep the slideToggle speed and the search bar being full page width?

Set width 100% to parent element .wpbsearchform keep in mind that depends what this element inherits. If doesnt work you can go with 100vw instead of 100%. For fixed elements you can try fadeToggle() instead.

@Snuffy, nailed it! 100vw in the parent element .wpbsearchform did the trick. Thank you so much for your help!
