# onKeyUp not firing for ESC in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keyboard-events

I have a page where I have to close a dialog when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed. I wrote the following **simplified** code example for this task:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function keyUpExample() {
alert('on' + event.type + ' event fired by ' + '"' + event.srcElement.id + '" ' + ' ' +        event.which) 
} 
</script>
</head>
<body id="myBody" onkeyup="keyUpExample()">
    Trying keyUp event: Press any key...
</body>
</html>
```

This works as expected under Chrome but is NOT working under IE 7. Is there any workaround on order to cope this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate - or at least answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery

Comment: Doesn't IE use `window.event` instead of just `event`?

Comment: Internet Explorer does not fire the keypress event for the Escape key.  (see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html). OnKeyDown is probably your best bet for the escape key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key events don't have to be caught by the body, but document or window works across browsers. Also, keyCode returns the correct value for keyup or down events.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Small Page</title>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function keyUpExample(e){
    e=e || window.event;
    var  who= e.target || e.srcElement;
    alert(e.type+' caught at '+who.nodeName+ ': key #'+e.keyCode) 
}
window.onload=function(){
    document.onkeyup= keyUpExample; 
    document.body.onkeyup= keyUpExample;    
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Trying keyUp event: Press any key...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: except when it is is event.which

Comment: @mplungjan: No, keyCode works in all major browsers for keyup and keydown events. You only have to worry about the which property in keypress events.

Comment: @Tim Okeee - that was a revelation

Comment: *"Key events don't have to be caught by the body, but document or window works across browsers"* - do you know of any documentation for that?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `event` as an argument to the callback, and check for `window.event` for IE.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function keyUpExample(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    alert('on' + e.type + ' event fired by ' + '"' + e.srcElement.id + '" ' + ' ' +        e.which) 
} 
</script>
</head>
<body id="myBody" onkeyup="keyUpExample()">
    Trying keyUp event: Press any key...
</body>
</html>
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/FNvgx/)

[`element.onkeyup` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onkeyup)

#### However

You're better off using a library which smooths out all the ugly cross-browser inconsistencies. Take your pick: jQuery, Prototype, YUI, Dojo, MooTools, RightJS...

Comment: Could you,please, specify a little bit more what should be done? I didn't understand.

Comment: What he says is that browsers interprete events on different ways. There are a lot of library's that fix this (sometimes extremely timeconsuming) problem for you.

Comment: I really appreciate a lot your effort and your code, but it is not working under IE7.

Comment: Sorry - I don't have an easy way to test thing in IE7. Could you provide more detail? But seriously, **this is why people use jQuery.**

Comment: HiMatt. I cn use jQuery and I am right now trying it. The point is that I cannot use an input field. I have to close a layer when ESC is pressed.

Comment: @Luixv I would recommend asking another question with the specific jQuery code that you're trying to use. I'm not sure what you mean by "I cannot use an input field."

Comment: Thanks Matt. I got a solution using jQuery. However the solution proposed by kennebec properly. I did +1 for you at every comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to use jQuery? If so, then you can accomplish it with [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

Using jQuery also means you can generally leave the cross-browser worries to somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function keyUpExample(e) {
  var evt = e || event;
  alert('on' + evt.type + ' event fired by ' + '"' + ((evt.srcElement)?evt.srcElement.id:evt.target.id) + '" ' + ' ' +        ((evt.which)?evt.which:evt.keyCode)) 
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? I couldn't get running neither under IE7 nor under Chrome :-(

Comment: Sorry, no. Do not have either here. However the event is event.keyCode for IE and event.which for many others. Try my edit

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very simple, a raw JavaScript solution could look kinda like this

```
function callback(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 27) {
    alert('Here you go!');
  }
}

if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', callback, false);
} else {
  document.attachEvent('onkeydown', callback);
}
```

Just attach it to the `document` no need for any onload trickery.

Also, as people suggested you, check `RightJS`, it's very lightweight and friendly, and you will be able to do things like those :)

http://rightjs.org/plugins/keys