# Triggering keyup event on input field in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

Basically I have a problem with triggering keyup event on input element in. In Firefox it works but in IE7 (or IE 8 in IE 7 mode) it doesn't. Is there a way to make this work (preferably in jQuery)?

I want `console` to print test each type I type a letter.

EDIT: In hurry I forgot the obligatory jsFiddle link -
http://jsfiddle.net/sWfNw/3/

Ok, here is alert which should work in IE regardless of version if I recall correctly.

Comment: The `console.log(something)` won't work on IE

Comment: ^ There are tools that will give you a console in IE too

Comment: Kindly Go through the below mentioned link which is the possible duplicate of the question you have asked [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554765/javascript-onkeyup-problem)

Comment: That is correct Michael. Post your answer and I'll accept it. bardiir and AmGates you received +1 for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi guys thanks for the help, but Michael Swan got it right, IE7 doesn't support console and that was the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Basically

```
jQuery('#inputfield').keyup(function(){ console.log('test'); })
```

should work even in IE7 - On the other hand it wouldn't be the first bug, you might want to try this:

```
jQuery('#inputfield').change(function(){ console.log('test'); })
```