# How can I close a modal popup on hitting escape?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have made a modal box popup functionality and I want to close this modal popup up box when someone hits the escape key, in all browsers. I have used the file `modal-window.min.js` for these popups.

How can I close these in response to this key?

Comment: refer to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery 

in addition i guest to use tinybox which doesn't have to do anything  with jquery

Answer (score 37):

With the `keydown` function:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) { 
  if (event.keyCode == 27) { 
    $('#modal_id').hide();
  }
});
```

> **Note:** Prefer using `keydown` for the Escape key as in some browsers the `keypress` event is only fired if the key outputs a character

Answer (score 19):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode === 27) { 
        $("#popdiv").fadeOut(500);
        //or
        window.close();
    } 
});
```

Comment: `$("#popdiv").fadeOut(500);` <- This line just fades the modal out, but the fade stays. This keeps the entire background page faded and unclickable.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc fade the proper div

Comment: it's keypress or keydown for escape key catch event ?

Comment: This doesn't currently work in Chrome, however the keydown suggestion below does.

Comment: agreed with @StaticVariable, but the sometimes keypress event only executes when it gives some output.

Answer (score 19):

For the people landing on this looking for a non-jQuery solution, here it is:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Escape') {
    // close modal here
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
   jQuery("#myModal").modal('toggle');
                 OR
   jQuery("#myModal").modal('hide');
  }
 });
</script>
```

Taken from: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/05/how-to-close-model-popup-on-escape-key.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one modal, you can use script below. I had to open so many modal in one page, thats why i wrote this script. This script closes modals one by one according to opening order with escape key. And also you don't need to define any modal name in script hence add once use everywhere.

```
var modals=[]; // array to store modal id

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.modal').modal({show: false, keyboard: false}); // disable keyboard because it conflicts below

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   //add modal id to array
   modals.push(event.target.id);
});


document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var isEscape = false;
    if ("key" in evt) {
        isEscape = (evt.key === "Escape" || evt.key === "Esc");
    } else {
        isEscape = (evt.keyCode === 27);
    }
    if (isEscape) {

        if(modals.length>0){
            //get last modal id by using pop(). 
            //This function also removes last item in array.
            var id = modals.pop();
            if($('#'+id).is(':visible')){ // if modal is not closed by click or close button
                $('#'+id).modal('toggle');
            }
        }else{
            alert("Could not find any modals!");
        }
    }
};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).keyup(function(event){
      if(event.which=='27'){
          $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
      }
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using AngularJs:
In case you have multiple modals,

assign a value to each modal, when you open the modal set it to true
when you close it set it to false.

```
//in your .js script

    document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        if (usersModal)
            $scope.hideUsersModal();
        else if (groupsModal)
            $scope.hideGroupsModal();
    }
```

Using Angular, `event.target` property indicates where you've set the ng-controller and `event.currentTarget` is the `#document`.