# Enable the ESC Key Chrome Embedded Framework

Tags: jquery, delphi, google-chrome, angularjs, chromium-embedded

I need to use the ESC key to close a modal in my application that is built with the Chrome Embedded Framework but it is disabled by default.

Is there a way to activate it?

CEF is embedded in a Delphi application. The front end is being implemented with AngularJS and jQuery.

Comment: Who opens the modal dialog? Delphi, JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript via jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the modal dialog is of the `alert()` type, [you cannot bind ESC key in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463368/javascript-close-alert-box). On the other hand, if the modal dialog is opened by a jQuery plugin ([like this one](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)), please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816497/close-modal-box-on-escape-key). You can also [hijack window.alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321574/how-to-auto-close-alert-boxes). However, if you cannot modify JavaScript code, you are left with [intercepting the modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575699/delphi-detect-when-a-new-form-has-been-created) within Delphi (which I am not familiar with)