# Ember.js: View listening for keypress event

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events

In my application I have a panel which contains some settings information. This panel is opened/closed with a button click, but I'd also like to be able to close it by hitting `esc` on the keyboard.

The code for my View looks like this:

```
Social.MainPanelView = Ember.View.extend({
    elementId: 'panel-account-settings',
    classNames: ['panel', 'closed'],
    keypress: function(e){
        console.log(e);
        console.log('keypress');
    },
    close: function(){
        this.$().prepareTransition().addClass("closed");
    }
});
```

I've tried keyup and keydown as well but nothing happens. I suspect that it's because that this isn't an "input" type View but just a standard view. So how can I trigger a method on a View from a key event?

I should clarify that this is not within the context of a Route for this particular element. I'm opening the panel standalone as can be seen in this video:

http://screencast.com/t/tDlyMud7Yb7e

**UPDATE 1**

[Here's a quick fiddle that I've created](http://jsfiddle.net/7GTQq/1/) to illustrate the issue I'm having. I can get the click event to trigger quite easily, but I'm looking for a page wide keyup event that will detect the esc key being pressed and trigger a method on a specific View:

Comment: This doesnt work for you?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery

Comment: Ricardo, I know that I can set up a listener for the entire body, but I need to be able to call a method on the `MainPanelView` when esc is pressed. That means I need to be able to do it from within Ember. At the very least I need to be able to set it up within Ember.

Answer (score 22):

For keyPress to work, you have to bring focus to the view. When it is an input, it works because you are bringing focus to it.

Something like this:

```
App = Em.Application.create();

App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
  updateKey: function(keyCode) {
    // Do what you gotta do
    this.set('shortcutKey', keyCode);
  },
  shortcutKey: null
});

App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    return this.$().attr({ tabindex: 1 }), this.$().focus();
  },

  keyDown: function(e) {

    this.get('controller').send('updateKey', e.keyCode);
  }
});
```

Here are a working example: http://jsbin.com/ihuzov/1

Comment: keyPress still doesn't work, but this solution works for keyDown or keyUp.

Answer (score 18):

I think you have misspelled the keypress event. It should be **keyPress**. For sake of completeness, the following are the events that can be handled by a View (taken from [Ember source/doc](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html)):

#### Event Names

Possible events names for any of the responding approaches described above
  are:

Touch events:

- `touchStart`
- `touchMove`
- `touchEnd`
- `touchCancel`

  Keyboard events
- `keyDown`
- `keyUp`
- `keyPress`

  Mouse events
- `mouseDown`
- `mouseUp`
- `contextMenu`
- `click`
- `doubleClick`
- `mouseMove`
- `focusIn`
- `focusOut`
- `mouseEnter`
- `mouseLeave`

  Form events:
- `submit`
- `change`
- `focusIn`
- `focusOut`
- `input`

  HTML5 drag and drop events:
- `dragStart`
- `drag`
- `dragEnter`
- `dragLeave`
- `drop`
- `dragEnd`

Comment: I think, if you call the events within an input-helper you have to write it with a hyphen like this {{input type="text" value=search key-press="query"}}. At least this works for me in Ember 1.7.0 and keyPress didn't.