# How to put other events (e.g. focusOut) for the onEvent of Textflied in ember.js to trigger action?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to change [emberjs's onEvent](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html#property_onEvent) which is the trigger to perform the associated view `action`. There seems to be just 2 options for onEvent: the default `enter`, and `keypress`. I'd like to know if I can have other options as well, such as `focusOut`.

### Small question

But first, I couldn't even get the non-default option to work:

```
Myapp.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    onEvent: 'keypress'
});
```

The text field didn't respond to key presses, but continued to respond to `enter`.

### Actual question

How can we let ember.js text field respond to other `onEvent`s to trigger the `action` specified in the view.  This is something I'm expecting:

HBS:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="themodel">
    {{view Myapp.TextField action="targetAction" valueBinding="myText"}}
</script>
```

JS view:

```
Myapp.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    // is this possible?
    onEvent: 'focusOut'
});
```

JS controller:

```
Myapp.ThemodelController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    targetAction: function(){
        var usertext = this.get('myText');
        // do stuff with the usertext ...
    }
});
```

### A workaround solution for the "Actual question"

This is a work-around as it doesn't modify `onEvent`, but directly lets `focusOut` trigger the targetAction:

JS view:

```
Myapp.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    focusOut: function(){
        this.get('controller').set('myText', this.get('value')).targetAction();
    }
});
```

But I really don't like this cumbersome implementation, so please let me know if there is a way to utilize `onEvent` with `focusOut`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced something similar to your "small problem", only instead of the text field only responding to enter, it would respond to neither keypresses nor enter.

The solution lies within [mavilein's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15347084/1377016) to this question - **the word "keypress" must be in camelCase, i.e "keyPress".** This applies whether it is used as a property name when extending the Ember.TextField class, as you had originally attempted, or as an attribute on the actual view element as Mike had suggested. I tried it both ways. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> But first, I couldn't even get the non-default option to work

Strange. There is [a test](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/tests/controls/text_field_test.js#L380) for exactly this behavior. Suggest having a look and see what's different in your use case.

> How can we let ember.js text field respond to other onEvents to trigger the action specified in the view.

Following the same pattern used in [Ember.TextField's insertNewLine fx](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_field.js#L139-L141)

```
Myapp.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  onEvent: 'focusOut',
  focusOut: function() {
    sendAction('focusOut', this, event);
  }
});
```

Comment: I guess I should do `textField.set('onEvent', 'keyPress');` instead of `onEvent: 'keyPress',` but I'm getting an error with `Myapp.TextField.set('onEvent', 'keyPress');`. The error message is: `has no method 'set'`

Comment: That makes sense. `Myapp.TextField` refers to the class not an instance.

Comment: True. Mike, do you know where I can add the set method for [TodoMVC's  view Ember.TextField](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/index.html#L14) or make keyPress work for its `action="createTodo"`? Thank you so much.

Comment: How about `{{view Ember.TextField id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" valueBinding="newTitle" action="createTodo" onEvent="keyPress"}}`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. `createTodo` is still only being called on enter.

Comment: strane - could be i am missing something obvious. Can you reproduce in a jsFiddle?