# Jquery fadeOut div with esc

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I am new to webdesign. Been doing it for half a year now. 
I am trying to work with JS and I can't figure this out...
I got this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
    $('div#contact1').click(function(e){    
        $('div#contact1').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('div#contact2').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }); 
    $('div.close3').click(function(e){    
        $('div#contact2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('div#contact1').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

I want to fadeout the div contact2 with the div#close3 and with the escape key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
        $('div#contact2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('div#contact1').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }
});
```

**Source:** [Which keycode for escape key with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery)

Comment: Somehow if I add anything to the js concerning the fadeout. The whole  fade in fade out wont work at all...

Comment: I don't understand, maybe you can debug to find out why and I'll try to fix it. If you copy/pasted my code, try again as I've updated it.

Comment: If you don't have any more questions, could you mark my answer as correct? Thanks :)