# Submit Form using ESC Key HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which doesn't need a submit button. I want the user to press the **ESC** key to submit the form.

How can I submit a form using the ESC key?

Comment: This sounds like the weirdest UX decision...

Comment: look at [keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) - but I have to agree with Rory ... `ESC` is probably the last key I would ever choose to use as a submit key!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which keycode for escape key with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What other key is similar to the enter key?

Comment: As strange as it sounds, what you're trying to do could be a legitimate case. Example: A modal form that does not have a save button because it automatically saves - in that case, an "escape" event may also trigger a save event to close the modal.

Comment: @technophobia yea, all cool, unless you are a user of this and have no idea that it saved, pulling your hair out finding the submit button

Comment: @ConsiderMe I'm reaching here...work with me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its what you want then use the

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) $('#your_form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question!

Comment: You're welcome :). Don't forget to check the answer as correct please.