# How to detect when user presses Esc in input field using Reagent

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I have an input field

```
[:input {:type "text"}]
```

and I need to detect when user presses an Esc key while editing that field. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add an `:on-key-up` (or `:on-key-down`) handler to the element:

```
[:input {:type "text"
         :on-key-up #(when (= 27 (.-which %))
                       (do-something-here))}]
```

Comment: Is 27 the key-code for escape?

Edit: yes it is, keycodes mapping here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm

Comment: Yes. I use code similar to above in my app. Plus this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery