# esc key event for jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have jquery dialog as closeOnescape as false. want to trigger an event based on esc key press how do i achieve it?
 this on also not working

```
 $(document).on("keypress","#popupid",function(e) {
        debugger;
        if (e.keycode === 27) {
            alert("esc key triggered");
        }
    });
```

Comment: put alert after debugger; alert(e.keycode) and check that what this gives

Comment: esc key code is 27 that you are using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery

Comment: plus it's keyCode*

Comment: I found issue, use keyCode instead of keycode

Comment: You need bind event on document , hide your `popupid` if visiable .

Answer (score 1):

Replace keypress by keyup function

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode === 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
        alert("esc key triggered");
     }
});
```

Explanations :
[Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode==27){
    //do smth
}});
```