# implementing Onclick button for Escape Key using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript below is used to close div when an ESC Key is clicked.

```
<script>
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if(event.which === 27) {
            alert('closed now');
            $('#content').hide();
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="content">My content to be closed is here</div>
```

Now what I want is to close the content from a button click which will then call Esc Key javascript function

```
<button id="close_content">Close</button>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which keycode for escape key with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery)

Comment: Right, and did you try anything? Where's your button code?

Comment: A mouse is not a keyboard, a click is not a keyup, you have to see them as two seperate events. You can react to them in the same way, but you need two different event handlers.

Comment: So you actually have no clue what your current script does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your script, when you click Close button the content "My content to be closed is here" will hide.
    `$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#close_content").click(function() {
          $("#content").hide();
        });
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a named function, then call it from both event handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function close_content() {
        alert('closed now');
        $("#content").hide();
    }

    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 27) {
            close_content();
        }
    }
    $("#close_content").click(close_content);
});
```

Comment: @Bamar, the close button does not close the div content when clicked