# How to close modal by pressing esc

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, solution

I am new to Javascript and I'd like to close this modal by pressing `esc` key, besides clicking on span. How to write it?

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
                        var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
                        var img2 = document.getElementById('myImg2');
                        var img3 = document.getElementById('myImg3');
                        var img4 = document.getElementById('myImg4');
                        var modalImg1 = document.getElementById("img01");
                        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

                            img.onclick = function()
                                {
                                    modal.style.display = "block";
                                    modalImg1.src = this.src;
                                    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                                }
                            img2.onclick = function()
                                {
                                    modal.style.display = "block";
                                    modalImg1.src = this.src;
                                    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                                }   
                            img3.onclick = function()
                                {
                                    modal.style.display = "block";
                                    modalImg1.src = this.src;
                                    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                                }   
                            img4.onclick = function()
                                {
                                    modal.style.display = "block";
                                    modalImg1.src = this.src;
                                    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                                }   

                            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                            span.onclick = function() 
                            { 
                                modal.style.display = "none"; 
                            }
```

I'm considering to add after that span:

```
window.onkeypress = function (event) 
                            {
                                if (event.keyCode == 27 && modal.style.display='block') 
                                    {
                                        modal.style.display='none';
                                    }
                            }
```

but don't honestly know what's wrong there

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need 2 equal sign in `display = 'block'` or else you _assign_ a value instead of _compare_ them ... e.g. `if (event.keyCode == 27 && modal.style.display == 'block')`

Comment: Nothing happened :( I mean now modal works, but can't close it by pressing esc...

Edit: thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress`:

```
window.onkeyup = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '27' && modal.style.display=='block') {
        modal.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Why?

Using `onkeypress` you'll get different key codes for different browsers. 
Check these threads on SO:
[Which keycode for escape key with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery/28502629)
And:
[How to detect escape key press with pure JS or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-pure-js-or-jquery)

Comment: Thank you so much Damian :) Now it's working perfectly